# Vaadin14 CDI skeleton - 403 forbidden

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin, wildfly, vaadin-flow

I am trying to launch the Vaadin 14 CDI demo project: https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow-cdi/tree/v14

But I am getting 403 forbidden messages every time I deploy it and trying to access it. I am using wildfly 27 for deployment and I dont see any error indicating why I am having problem with launching it.

The v14 springboot demo and the v23 CDI demo works just fine.

What could cause this issue on my side?

I tried earlier versions of the v14 branch, same issue. Every other vaadin demo works just fine, so it is rather strange for me, because that indicates on my side everything is good.

Answer (score 1):

WildFly 27 is a Jakarta EE 10 server. You cannot run a Jakarta EE 8 based, javax namespace, in WildFly 27. You'd need to either upgrade your dependencies to be Jakarta EE 10 based or use WildFly 26.

The the other option would be to use the [wildfly-deployment-transformer-feature-pack](https://groups.google.com/g/wildfly/c/hVbijKO7do8).